# part of word bold in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to highglight part of a title, as you can see above. It doesn't seem to have any effect, how can I achieve what I'm after?

```html
<h1> <strong>BOLD</strong>NOTBOLD</h1>
```

Comment: `h1` (in fact all headings) are **bold** by default. You have to reset that.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by setting the font-weight to `normal` instead of `large` which is the default font weight. Here's a snippet.

```css
h1 { font-weight:normal; }
```

```html
<h1><strong>Bold</strong>Not Bold</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset the `font-weight` of your `h1` tag

```css
h1{
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1><strong>BOLD</strong>NOTBOLD</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

A header is bold by default, you have to "unbold"  it:

```css
h1{
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello normal <strong>and then bold</strong></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h1>Bold<span style="font-weight: lighter">Not Bold</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thought not wrong, IMO this is the wrong way around. If this is only one header, this might be a solution, but in general al headers should behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

Header tags already have made bold, if you still want to highlight it you can use some other properties like make it Italic, set font-color, etc.,